# Call a functions inside a function already call

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to understand how to use function.

I have 2 functions inside the file functions.js:

- `getAllIssueForSCII()`
- `test()`

I have a another file (index.js) for call function but got some problem for call the function `test()`.

**functions.js**

```
function getAllIssueForSCII(){
  var options = {
    ...
  };

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      request(options, function (error, response, data) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          console.log('JIRA login success!!')
          var json = JSON.parse(data);
          resolve(json);            
        } else {
          console.log('error: ' + response.statusCode + ': ' + data.statusMessage)
        }

      })
    })
}

function test(){

  /* We recover the value of the priority and we give it a score according to its value */
  var priority = json.issues[i].fields.priority.name;
  var score1 = 0 ;  

  switch (priority){
        ...
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
var functions = require('./functions.js')

functions.getAllIssueForSCII().then(function(json){
  for (var i=0; i<json.issues.length;i++){
    console.log(json.issues[i].key);
    functions.test(); //Error
  }
});
```

Comment: What environment is this? It looks like NodeJS. If so, your function in `Function.js` are never exported, so they are not visible frmo `Index.js`.

Comment: What’s the “Error”?

Comment: Yes it's node JS, i have already exports but don't show in this script

Comment: Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: Inside `function test(){` you trying to refer to `json` object that was not passed to this function. You should pass the json object in index.js file `functions.test(json);` and get it in your function `function test(json){`

Comment: So I put json inside functions.test and function test
But now the error say me that i is not defined ( in issue[i]), normaly I defined it into my loop for

Comment: ah, I didn't notice it, so in this case, you can do this:
`for (let i=0; i < json.issues.length; i++) { functions.test(json.issues[i]); }`
and `function test(data) { var priority = data.fields.priority.name;`

Comment: i'm doing (json,i) it work but another solution maybe ?

Comment: Ok, it's better to read, thanks you :)